# How do I schedule a firebase notification?

Tags: java, android, firebase, time, notifications

I am trying to send a notification to the user at the time he wants it but don't know how to do it. May I get some help?

I tried searching across the web and expected an answer but no one had answered it yet. I found one question similar and it had only one answer which points to https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There is no public API to schedule sending messages through FCM. You can either schedule sending messages in the Firebase console, or you'll have to create your own scheduling solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to schedule Firebase notifications:

**Using Cloud Functions for Firebase:** One way to schedule Firebase notifications is by using Cloud Functions for Firebase. You can write a function that sends a notification at a specific time using the Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) API and schedule it to run at the desired time using the built-in Scheduler for Cloud Functions.

**Using Firebase Cloud Scheduler:** Firebase Cloud Scheduler is a fully managed cron job service that allows you to schedule function invocations. You can use it to schedule a Cloud Function that sends a notification at a specific time.

**Using Firebase Realtime Database:** Another way to schedule notifications is by storing the scheduled time and message in the Firebase Realtime Database, and then creating a Cloud Function that listens for changes in the database and sends the notification when the scheduled time arrives.

**Using Firebase Cloud Firestore:** You can also use Firebase Cloud Firestore, to schedule a notification. You can create a collection of scheduled notifications, where each document represents a notification to be sent at a specific time. And then you can create a Cloud Function that listens for changes in the collection and sends the notification when the scheduled time arrives.